# Orchard CMS - Can i Copy the website contents to another site? (First Time Publish)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, orchardcms

I've setup Orchard on **cms.mysite.com**

I didn't set it up on **www.mysite.com**, because during the stages of when i configure my site for the first time, i don't want it being seen via **www.mysite.com**

I'm planning to follow these steps:

1. Configure my site via **cms.mysite.com**
2. Create another IIS website, running ASP.NET 4 on **www.mysite.com**
3. When the site's ready, copy the website contents (file sytem) to **www.mysite.com**
4. Remove **cms.mysite.com**
5. All future changes to the site (e.g by editors/authors) will be done on the main site (**www.mysite.com**)

This should work right - since all the content is stored in the database?

Or am i doing this the wrong way?

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem here. This is pretty much what I do most of the time -- I work off of localhost during development and just copy to the server once I'm done.

Comment: @Ragesh - so you just make your changes, then publish (using VS) the Orchard.Web project, FTP, then that's it? What about any web.config changes - wouldn't it need to know that the base url is `www.mysite.com` instead of `localhost.www.mysite.com`?

Comment: I don't use a subdomain during development; it just runs off of a local URL and port http://localhost:1234 (no subdomains or subfolders). And, yes, after you deploy you should log in to your admin panel and update the Base URL setting.

Comment: At the very least, you'll want to avoid using subfolders or you'll run into problems like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670696/orchard-cms-configure-base-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work perfectly fine.

But remember to change the base URL setting (*in Dashboard --> Settings --> General*) to the new URL.

And also make sure that the IIS App Pool (under which the new app runs) user account has read/write access to App_Data folder in the Orchard root.